# JQuery added via NuGet Manager doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web Forms CRUD project and need to show a confirm dialog box every time a user want to perform an action over the SQL database.
For that purpose I' decided to use Jquery and searching in the internet I found a very good example but they use CDN for Jquery-Jquery ui- Jquery ui themes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and works fine, but I decided to use a newest version of Jquery always using CDN so I changed the above code for this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and still working fine...my problem comes when I add the Jquery-Jquery ui from NuGet and then add those packages to my web form and comment the other lines that use CDN

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If I do that the confirm dialog box doesn't appear at all but why? I guess that just change the source of the Jquery package from CDN to the one that the NuGET package added to my project shouldn't have to created any problem.

Could you please help me and tell me why my confirm dialog box doesn't show up.

this is what I got in my project after added Jquery ui via NuGet

[image]

Comment: It's not a good idea to always refer to the latest version. Grab the latest version that works for your app, and refer to that. Then if you want to update, change the version number to the newer version and re-test. That way you don't get surprised by some breaking change that you weren't aware of.

Comment: You're not using the same CSS files. CDN: `/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css`; Local: `/themes/base/dialog.css`.

Comment: @krlzlx yes, I could't find the theme smoothness in the themes that NuGet added, should I added via other way?

Comment: I don't know if it's your problem. Maybe if you show your code, I could try. Maybe your dialog box is there but not `visible` due to CSS. Have you an error, for example in Firefox `Firebug` ?

Comment: @mason you are right